# NAT - Two hosts with different private IP addresses but same public IP

Tags: nat

I'm studying the NAT-process and I've a doubt about addressing. When the NAT translates the private IP address to a public IP address, it can translate, if properly configurated, different private IP to the same public IP . How is it possible that two hosts use the same public IP? I mean, if I ping that IP, would I get a response from both of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are variants of NAT, and you are referring to NAPT (Network Address Port Translation) as described in *[RFC 2663, IP Network Address Translator (NAT) Terminology and Considerations](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2663)*:

> 4.1.2. Network Address Port Translation (NAPT)
>
> NAPT extends the notion of translation one step further by also
> translating transport identifier (e.g., TCP and UDP port numbers, ICMP
> query identifiers). This allows the transport identifiers of a number
> of private hosts to be multiplexed into the transport identifiers of a
> single external address. NAPT allows a set of hosts to share a single
> external address. Note that NAPT can be combined with Basic NAT so
> that a pool of external addresses are used in conjunction with port
> translation.
>
> For packets outbound from the private network, NAPT would translate
> the source IP address, source transport identifier and related fields
> such as IP, TCP, UDP and ICMP header checksums. Transport identifier
> can be one of TCP/UDP port or ICMP query ID. For inbound packets, the
> destination IP address, destination transport identifier and the IP
> and transport header checksums are translated.

Basically, both the IPv4 and transport protocol addresses (TCP/UDP ports or ICMP Query ID) are translated, not just the IPv4 address. That means that you translate to a single IPv4 address, but the various transport addresses also, so it is not dependent on just the IPv4 address. This creates a limitation that means you can only use NAPT with TCP, UDP, and ICMP. Other existing or future transport protocols are broken by NAPT, as are some applications or application-layer protocols that use TCP or UDP.

This is further explained in *[RFC 3022, Traditional IP Network Address Translator (Traditional NAT)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3022)*:

> 2.2. Overview of NAPT
>
> Say, an organization has a private IP network and a WAN link to a
> service provider.  The private network's stub router is assigned a
> globally valid address on the WAN link and the remaining nodes in the
> organization have IP addresses that have only local significance.  In
> such a case, nodes on the private network could be allowed
> simultaneous access to the external network, using the single
> registered IP address with the aid of NAPT.  NAPT would allow mapping
> of tuples of the type (local IP addresses, local TU port number) to
> tuples of the type (registered IP address, assigned TU port number).
>
> This model fits the requirements of most Small Office Home Office
> (SOHO) groups to access external network using a single service
> provider assigned IP address.  This model could be extended to allow
> inbound access by statically mapping a local node per each service TU
> port of the registered IP address.
>
> In the example of figure 3 below, stub A internally uses class A
> address block 10.0.0.0/8.  The stub router's WAN interface is assigned
> an IP address 138.76.28.4 by the service provider.
>
> ```
>                                  \ | /
>                                +-----------------------+
>                                |Service Provider Router|
>                                +-----------------------+
>                              WAN |
>                                  |
>              Stub A .............|....
>                                  |
>      ^{s=138.76.28.4,sport=1024, |  v{s=138.76.29.7, sport = 23,
>      ^ d=138.76.29.7,dport=23}   |  v d=138.76.28.4, dport = 1024}
>                      +------------------+
>                      |Stub Router w/NAPT|
>                      +------------------+
>                        |
>                        |  LAN
>  --------------------------------------------
>     |        ^{s=10.0.0.10,sport=3017, |  v{s=138.76.29.7, sport=23,
>     |        ^ d=138.76.29.7,dport=23} |  v d=10.0.0.10, dport=3017}
>     |                                  |
>    +--+      +--+                    +--+
>    |--|      |--|                    |--|
>   /____\    /____\                  /____\
>  10.0.0.1  10.0.0.2   .....        10.0.0.10
>
>   Figure 3: Network Address Port Translation (NAPT) Operation
> ```
>
> When stub A host 10.0.0.10 sends a telnet packet to host 138.76.29.7,
> it uses the globally unique address 138.76.29.7 as destination, and
> sends the packet to it's primary router.  The stub router has a static
> route for the subnet 138.76.0.0/16 so the packet is forwarded to the
> WAN-link.  However, NAPT translates the tuple of source address
> 10.0.0.10 and source TCP port 3017 in the IP and TCP headers into the globally unique 138.76.28.4 and a uniquely assigned TCP port, say
> 1024, before the packet is forwarded.  Packets on the return path go
> through similar address and TCP port translations for  the target IP
> address and target TCP port.  Once again, notice that this requires no
> changes to hosts or routers.  The translation is completely
> transparent.
>
> In this setup, only TCP/UDP sessions are allowed and must originate
> from the local network.  However, there are services such as DNS that
> demand inbound access.  There may be other services for which an
> organization wishes to allow inbound session access.  It is possible
> to statically configure a well known TU port service [RFC 1700] on the
> stub router to be directed to a specific node in the private network.
>
> In addition to TCP/UDP sessions, ICMP messages, with the exception of
> REDIRECT message type may also be monitored by NAPT router.  ICMP
> query type packets are translated similar to that of TCP/UDP packets,
> in that the identifier field in ICMP message header will be uniquely
> mapped to a query identifier of the registered IP address.  The
> identifier field in ICMP query messages is set by Query sender and
> returned unchanged in response message from the Query responder.  So,
> the tuple of (Local IP address, local ICMP query identifier) is mapped
> to a tuple of (registered IP address, assigned ICMP query Identifier)
> by the NAPT router to uniquely identify ICMP queries of all types from
> any of the local hosts. Modifications to ICMP error messages are
> discussed in a later section, as that involves modifications to ICMP
> payload as well as the IP and ICMP headers.
>
> In NAPT setup, where the registered IP address is the same as the IP
> address of the stub router WAN interface, the router has to be sure to
> make distinction between TCP, UDP or ICMP query sessions originated
> from itself versus those originated from the nodes on local network.
> All inbound sessions (including TCP, UDP and ICMP query sessions) are
> assumed to be directed to the NAT router as the end node, unless the
> target service port is statically mapped to a different node in the
> local network.
>
> Sessions other than TCP, UDP and ICMP query type are simply not
> permitted from local nodes, serviced by a NAPT router.